# How to select last td in specified tr tag using css

Tags: css, html

I'm making a event bulletin board page. for my Individual homepage Using JSP, HTML/CSS5.

I want to implement Only last td's border-bottom color as purple (except this, others are green.)

The tr tag is specified as event_tr class.

How Can I solve This?

This is what I have so far:

**CSS CODES**

```
.event_tr td {
    border-bottom:1px solid green ;
    padding-bottom: 5px;

}

.event_tr td:last-child  {
    border-bottom:10px solid purple !important;
    padding-bottom: 5px; 
}
```

**HTML CODES**
This Codes is just a part of tr Tag in Table, and This is repeated By Database, JSP's repeat Syntax(while, for ,etc..)

```
            <tr class="event_tr">
                <td>
                    <a href="event_view.jsp?navcd=event&subnavcd=ONGOING!&num=6">
                        <img src="../images/event/juniel1.jpg"width="300" height="150" style="">
                    </a>
                    <ul>
                        <li style="padding-top: 10px;">
                            <a href="event_view.jsp?navcd=event&subnavcd=ONGOING!&num=6">
                                ALL FREE!
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="event_view.jsp?navcd=event&subnavcd=ONGOING!&num=6">
                                ALL FREE!
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="event_view.jsp?navcd=event&subnavcd=ONGOING!&num=6">
                                FROM 2017-08-11 TO ~ 2017-09-21 
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Regards,

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Your shown table row only _has_ one single cell, which also makes that cell the _last_ child, and `.event_tr td:last-child` selects that perfectly fine.

Comment: I'm Sorry and thanks Your feedback, This is just a part, and This is repeated By DataBase, JSP's While syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Since all text content of your TD is inside `a` tags, you probably should address that `a` tag:

```
.event_tr td:last-child a {
    color: purple; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback,but I want to add not a tag but td tag's border-bottom attribute.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly you said that your tr tag is repeated inside the table then you probably gonna need this instead of what you have right now

```
table .event_tr td {
    border-bottom:1px solid green;
    padding-bottom:5px;
}

table .event_tr:last-child td {
    border-bottom:10px solid purple;
    padding-bottom:5px;
}
```

Comment: The border-bottom attribute is not working. I try to change this as color,and I confirmed that it is applied contents in a tag

Anyway, thanks your feedback :).

Answer (score 0):

You should address the `tr` tag instead of `td`. Try this:

```
.event_tr:last-child td {
    border-bottom:10px solid purple !important;
    padding-bottom: 5px; 
}
```

Comment: The border-bottom attribute is not working. I try to change this as color,and I confirmed that it is applied contents in a tag

Anyway, thanks your feedback. :)

Answer (score 0):

It works the way you wrote it, you just forgot to put the whole thing into a `table` tag, then the purple border appears:

```css
.event_tr td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.event_tr td:last-child {
  border-bottom: 10px solid purple !important;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="event_tr">
    <td>
      <a href="event_view.jsp?navcd=event&subnavcd=ONGOING!&num=6">
        <img src="../images/event/juniel1.jpg" width="300" height="150">
      </a>
      <ul>
        <li style="padding-top: 10px;">
          <a href="event_view.jsp?navcd=event&subnavcd=ONGOING!&num=6">
                                ALL FREE!
                            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="event_view.jsp?navcd=event&subnavcd=ONGOING!&num=6">
                                ALL FREE!
                            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="event_view.jsp?navcd=event&subnavcd=ONGOING!&num=6">
                                FROM 2017-08-11 TO ~ 2017-09-21 
                            </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```